# It is possible to use custom heroku dyno sleep time?

Tags: heroku

so i have hosted my node js webpage in heroku and i really like the dyno sleep, it's comfortable and i dont waste dyno credits when people don't visit my webpage, but it is posble to change the dyno inactivity sleep time from 30 minutes to, for example, 5 minutes? Already searched in my webpage options and i cannot find anything, If this is possible that would be great for not very big projects, if its not i hope a heroku developer sees this question abd like my idea and add it, it could be so useful. :)
Thanks for reading my question.

Comment: No, this is not configurable.

Answer (score 0):

The inactivity time (30 min) is not configurable.

The only other option you have is to control the start/stop of the Dyno using the CLI

```
# stop the app
heroku ps:scale web=0 -a myAppName
```